# as3 StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING does not fire

Tags: actionscript-3

I added an Eventlistener to the stage with:
stage.addEventListener(flash.events.StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING, keepInLandscape);

When testing on a device, the changing event never fires. But the change event (StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE) fires.

Does StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING need certain settings in application.xml to fire?

I have

visible-true
fullScreen-true
autoOrients-true
aspectRatio-landscape

and want to keep landscape mode and prevent to go to portrait mode..

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation for Stage there's this little note:

`Important: orientationChanging events are not dispatched on Android devices.`

Just guessing that this may be your case.

Answer (score 0):

If StageOrientationEvent is not fired you can try the same with Event.RESIZE and check if stageWidth or stageHeight is the largest

Comment: Yes resize is fireing.